# How to get index of a string in an array? array_search() not working

Tags: php, arrays, search

I'm using a text file as database and i'm trying to get the index value.
Text file:

```
0982|Chiara|chiaramella|543254
7134|Paolo|pablo752|675474
9564|Andrea|andry8239|39377874
3122|Luca|luka7|26887543
4456|Riccardo|riccard904|6832787645
9721|Fabio|fab78|38307696
3284|Francesco|frafra54|9325454
9555|Luigi|lulu14|0055468
1485|Matteo|matty990|897103464
0986|Laura|lau3245|324891000
3714|Claudio|cla235|36464820
9986|Giovanni|giojo982|0005405
8244|Stefano|stefy734|45367
7731|Marco|markkkk998|355647689
2123|Roberto|robn88|809678741
```

and this piece of code to get the index:

```
$db_friends = file("db_friends.txt");
$db_friends = array_map('trim', $db_friends);
$key = array_search('7134', $db_friends);
echo $key;
```

The echo result, should be give me "1", but maybe there is an error because is always empty and i'm not figured out why? Any help? Please! Thanks a lot!

Comment: why do you redefine `$db_friends` ?

Comment: To remove the spaces left from file() function, no?

Comment: consider a 'real' database they are MUCH easier to use

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but at the moment are much difficult the queries for me ... :(

Comment: Do you want to include rows where `7134` is in the long number at the end, or only when it's the number at the beginning of each line?

Comment: You should parse the file and turn it into an associative array.

Comment: you will write 90% less code, and need to know basic queries at some point. i always regretted how long i stuck to flat files for db's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_search` only matches array elements that match *completely*, not those that *contain* the given string, but have more than that.

You could first extract the numerical value of each string, and only then continue with `array_search`, like this:

```
$key = array_search('7134', array_map('intval', $db_friends));
```

Comment: This will evaluate to true if the row contains the id anywhere, not at the beginning.

Comment: True, but OP is not clear on that. I added a variant that will be more restrictive.

Comment: @trincot your solution its working... but, can you build your code without using a function? Its possible? Thanks.

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer so that it does not use an inline anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

The `array_search` try to find a exactly value, for instance:

```
$array = ['value one'];

var_dump(array_search('one', $array)); //= false
var_dump(array_search('value one', $array)); //= 0
```

---

The `$db_friends` is something like a `["2123|Roberto|robn88|809678741", "0982|Chiara..."]` this not have any values with exactly "2123", for this reason the `array_search` not work.

---

To fix that you can use `explode()` to create another array and after find it using `array_search`:

```
$file = file('db_friends.txt');

foreach($file as $line){
     $db_friends[] = explode('|', trim($line));
}

$key = array_search('7134', array_column($db_friends, '0'));

echo $key; //= 1
```

In this situation the we create a new array inside another (because of `explode()`) and we try to find `7134` inside the first column of this new array.

Comment: Your explanation is very good, and i like a lot your solution... but are you sure its working?
Because i have copy your code, and nothing happen... again :(

Comment: I test it now, I running on PHP 7.1, however the `array_column()` is available since PHP 5.5. The result is `1`. If I change `7134` to `7731` this return `13` for example.

Comment: How is it possible... i'm using xampp on php 5.6 with clean file... damn! :(

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each row, checking if the row starts with that id.

Complete Code:

```
$db_friends = file("db_friends.txt");
$rows = array_map('trim', $db_friends);
$id = '7134';
$index = -1;

foreach ($rows as $i => $row) {
    if (substr($row, 0, strlen($id)) === $id) {
        $index = $i;
    }
}

// $index now contains the index of the row


// As a function
function getIndexOfIdInFile($file, $id) {
    $file = file("db_friends.txt");
    $file = array_map('trim', $file);

    foreach ($file as $i => $row) {
        if (substr($row, 0, strlen($id)) === $id) {
            // Return the index of the id if we have found it
            return $i;
        }
    }

    // Return -1 if the id cannot be found
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: How is `explode(file_get_contents($f) "\n");` different from `file($f);` ?

Comment: @symcbean It's essentially the same as `file($f, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`

Comment: @symcbean And since he's calling `trim()` afterward, they'll be the same since `trim()` will also remove the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the array to an associative array.

```
$db_friends_assoc = array();
foreach ($db_friends as $friend) {
    list($id, $lastname, $username, $code) = explode('|', $friend);
    $db_friends_assoc[$id] = array('lastname' => $lastname, 'username' => $username, 'code' => $code);
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
$key = $db_friends_assoc['7134'];
```

Answer (score 0):

array_search() is working fine - it is your expectations which are wrong. The array_search() function looks for an element in the array containing *only* the value passed as a parameter, not a value containing, beginning with or ending in the search value.

If the first value in the dataset is unique, then you could use that as an array index:

```
$data=array();
$f=fopen('yourfile.txt', 'r');
While (($r=fgetcsv($f, 0, '|') && !feof($f)) {
  $i=array_shift($r);
  $data[$i]=$r;
}

print_r $data['7134'];
```

Or simply...

```
preg_match('/\n7134\|(.*)/', file_get_contents('yourfile.txt'), $matches);
print $matches[0];
```

However using files for maintaining data not scale well - there are problems with capacity, concurrency and performance. Thats why we use DBMS like mongodb or mysql.

Comment: Your "simply" solution, return the entire line/string... and not the index.

Comment: That's what it was intended to do. I was trying to keep the regex simple for illustration purposes.